# how to create vector in c#

Tags: c#

I have a set of servers for which I need the names, but I only want those that are currently available so I need a dynamically sized array.  What data structure can I use to store these.

Comment: please clarify what are you aming to do?

Comment: I think an List<T> will do what you need. But first please provide more info..

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use the the generic `List<T>` class, as in `List<string>`.

Let's say you have your server names in a comma-separated values string.  Then you can use the Split and `ToList()` extension method (on IEnumerable) to convert it to a dynamically-sized list.

```
 string input = "server1,server2,server3";
 List<string> serverNames = input.Split(',').ToList();
```

Or if you are checking them one at a time using some other method.

```
 List<string> serverNames = new List<string>();
 foreach (var server in GetAvailableServers())
 {
     if (server.IsAvailable)
     {
         serverNames.Add( server );
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A rough equivalent to C++'s `Vector<t>` in C# is a `List<t>`. Works as a dynamic array, allowing you to List.Add() and access it via index.

E.G.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("John");
names.Add("Mike");

foreach (string name in names)
{
  evaluate(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> servers = new List<string>();
servers.Add("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `List<T>` class.